# Join consecutive pairs in list - Python

Tags: python

I would like to take a list input (could have a variety of lengths) and create new lists joining each potential consecutive pair.

For example:

```
mylist = ['07', '05', '66', '06755', '04']
```

Would return as follows:

```
['0705', '66', '06755', '04']
['07', '0566', '06755', '04']
['07', '05', '6606755', '04']
['07', '05', '66', '0675504']
```

I've written the code below, but I was hoping there could be a better approach, as I'm worried that the slicing could run into problems.

```py
def joinConsecutive(nums):

    parts = len(nums)
    newNums = []

    # Join 1st and 2nd parts
    merge1 = [''.join(nums[0:2])] + nums[2:]
    newNums.append(merge1)

    # Join 2nd and 3rd parts, etc.
    i = 1
    while i <= parts - 2:
        start = nums[0:i]
        mid = [''.join(nums[i:i+2])]

        # When joining 2nd-to-last and last parts, this end just gets ignored
        end = nums[i+2:]
        newNums.append(start + mid + end)

        i += 1

    return newNums
```

```py
joinConsecutive(mylist)

[['0705', '66', '06755', '04'],
 ['07', '0566', '06755', '04'],
 ['07', '05', '6606755', '04'],
 ['07', '05', '66', '0675504']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is fine (slicing never raises an `IndexError`, it returns empty lists instead).

You could however improve readability by using try/except and enumerate:

```
def join_consecutive_values(mylist):
    result = []
    for i, value in enumerate(mylist): 
        try: 
            merged_value = value + mylist[i+1] 
        except IndexError:  # we're done!
            break 
        new_list = mylist[:i] + [merged_value] + mylist[i+2:] 
        result.append(new_list) 
   return result
```

Answer (score 3):

Use some index math and a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [mylist[:i] + [mylist[i]+mylist[i+1]] + mylist[i+2:] for i in range(len(mylist)-1)]
[['0705', '66', '06755', '04'], ['07', '0566', '06755', '04'], ['07', '05', '6606755', '04'], ['07', '05', '66', '0675504']]
```

Don't worry about "slicing problems" as Python will automatically take care of out-of-range slice indices for you (by returning an empty list).

Answer (score 0):

```
def joinConsecutive(mylist):
    output=[]
    for i,val in enumerate(mylist[:-1]):
        newlist=mylist.copy()
        newlist[i]=val+newlist.pop(i+1)
        output.append(newlist)
    return(output)
```

```
joinConsecutive(mylist)
[['0705', '66', '06755', '04'],
 ['07', '0566', '06755', '04'],
 ['07', '05', '6606755', '04'],
 ['07', '05', '66', '0675504']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def joinConsecutive(nums):
    newNums = []
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        tmp = nums.copy()
        tmp[i] = tmp[i] + tmp[i + 1]
        tmp.pop(i + 1)
        newNums.append(tmp)
    return newNums
```